# PowerShell - searching for existing files generates empty output

Tags: powershell

I wish to search for specific files listed in searchFiles and pipe their locations to TestFileLocation.CSV. However, my current script only generates an empty CSV. What am I missing?

My TestFindFile.csv is of the form:

```
Name
123.pdf
321.pdf
aaa.pdf
```

SNIPPET

```
$searchFiles = Import-CSV 'C:\Data\SCRIPTS\PS1\TestFindFile.csv' -Header ("Name")
$source = 'C:\Data'

ForEach($File in $searchFiles) 
{
    Get-ChildItem $source -Filter $File -rec | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | select-object FullName | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path c:\data\scripts\ps1\TestFileLocation.csv
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were overwriting the CSV for each iteration of the loop.

```ps1
$searchFiles = Import-CSV 'C:\Data\SCRIPTS\PS1\TestFindFile.csv' -Header ("Name")
$source = 'C:\Data'
$outputPath = 'c:\data\scripts\ps1\TestFileLocation.csv'

$searchFiles |  ForEach-Object {
    # Silently continue to try to ignore error like
    # not being able to read path's which are too long
    Get-ChildItem $source -Filter $_ -rec -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | select-object FullName 
} | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path $outputPath
```

### Example using AlphaFS

A comment asked for an example using AlphaFS because it claims to overcome the long path issue.  I'm not going into all the details, but here is how I got it to work.

```
# download and unzip to c:\alpahfs
# dir C:\AlphaFS\* -Recurse -File | Unblock-File 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('C:\AlphaFS\lib\net451\AlphaFS.dll')
$searchFiles = Import-CSV 'C:\Data\SCRIPTS\PS1\TestFindFile.csv' -Header ("Name")
$source = 'C:\Data'
$outputPath = 'c:\data\scripts\ps1\TestFileLocation.csv'

    $searchFiles |  ForEach-Object {
        $files = [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($source,'*',[System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories) 
        $files | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject] @{FileName = $_} }
    } | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path $outputPath
# type $outputPath
```

Comment: @val What file path, the one in the code or the one in the CSV?
Update: In case you mean the path to the CSV, I made it a variable.

Comment: Your solution worked on my test case. However, when I attempt to run a search on my server I get "Get-ChildItem: The specified path, file name, or both are too long." I suspect the file path to the files on the server may be getting too long. However, I don't understand if this hinders the search or only when it tries to write to the output csv.

Comment: This is a known issue in PowerShell.  See [this PowerShell UserVoice issue](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11685975-long-path-support).  Meaning if the path is too long, PowerShell cannot read it.

I'll update the script as best I can to ignore the errors and continue, but I've heard reports that this doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: OK- i see that if i have a file that is longer than 260 characters it will not appear in my CSV list. This seems difficult to generate...

Comment: Yes, If you need this feature please vote up the [PowerShell UserVoice issue](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11685975-long-path-support).

Comment: Any idea how I would incorporate AlphaFS command into my snippet? I followed your links to this statement: C:\> [Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.Directory]::EnumerateDirectories($Env:WinDir, 'a*')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114170/discussion-between-travis-plunk-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

If your .csv file contains the header "Name", there is no need to again declare it when running `Import-Csv`.

The reason the output is empty is that you are searching for an Object which contains the property Name (imported from the TestFindFile.csv). Search for `$File.Name`. Also pull commands outside the loop that don't need to be there:

```
$searchFiles | Select -ExpandProperty Name | % {
   Get-ChildItem $source -Filter $_ -Recurse | where {!$_.PSIsContainer}
} | select-object FullName | export-csv -notypeinformation -delimiter '|' -path c:\data\scripts\ps1\TestFileLocation.csv
```